# Python math.arctan() wrong result?

Tags: python, python-2.7, discrete-mathematics

I am using python shell as a calculator, but I don't know why it can't handle -28/96 as an input for atan function:

[image: math.atan wrong answer]

My question is:
Why is this wrong?

Comment: Do you know what `-28/96` is? Python appears to be handling it just fine.

Comment: OK. I got it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-28/96` is -1 in python 2 (integer division is the default for integers)

Turn that to `-28/96.0` you'll get the result you want.

(or switch to python 3)

BTW: 3.14 is a very bad approximation for `Pi` unless you like ovoïd circles :)

Use `math.pi` instead.

(I just saw that you wrote `28.0/96` the first time, which was correct! Your subconscient was aware of the bug :))

Comment: 0 to -1: Fixed. I just learned something today! I should avoid to perform integer division on negative numbers by hand ;)

Answer (score 3):

Python handles it correctly. Python interprets "-28/96" as int divides int, so it returns the largest previous integer of "-28/96", namely, -1. What you need is "-28.0/96" and then python 2.7 will interpret the expression as float division and handle it as your wish.

Also, the same expression will return a double precise float in python 3, namely, "-0.2916666666666667".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the result of `-28/96`:

```
>>> -28/92
-1
>>> math.atan(-1)
-0.7853981633974483
```

So python uses integer division for integers, not float division.

```
>>> math.atan(-28.7/96)
-0.2905008632137447
```

gives the correct result